# Include main queries results to sub queries condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "products" and a table "links". every product can have multiple links, each link can have many sales, clicks and impressions, but doesn't necessarily have all of them. I want to get a list of links of a certain product matching some criteria for them. I want to get this data grouped per day and campaign and link banner size.

The following query works correctly, but it's much slower than it could be. The problem is that the subqueries get the data for all link ids and it's just filtered in the end. The overall query would become much faster if the sub queries included something like
`where link_id IN (...)` but I only know the link_ids from the main query, not before

if I try to add
`where link_id = l.id`
it's obviously an unknown column, because the sub query doesn't have access to the main queries results.

how can I let the sub queries only look up data for the link_Ids that the main query found? I could split it up to 2 complete separate queries, but is this possible in one query?

```
select p.id, p.name, l.id, l.banner_size, 
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'sales' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_sales,
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_clicks,
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'impressions' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_impressions,
                    t1.dt
                from links l
                inner join products p
                    on p.id = l.product_id
                left join
                    (
                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(clicked) dt, 'sales' as col 
                        from sales
                        where clicked >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and clicked <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(clicked), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'clicks' 
                        from clicks_source1
                        where created >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and created <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(created), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(time) dt, 'clicks' 
                        from clicks_source2
                        where time >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and time <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(time), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'impressions' 
                        from impression_source1
                        where created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and created <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(created), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(time) dt, 'impressions' 
                        from impression_source2
                        where time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and time <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(time), link_id        

                    ) t1 on t1.link_id = l.id
                where l.agent_id = 300 
                and p.id = 3454
                and l.banner_size = 48
                and p.company NOT IN (13592, 28189) 
                group by c.id, l.banner_size, t1.dt
                having (total_sales + total_clicks + total_impressions) > 0
                order by dt DESC, p.id ASC, l.banner_size ASC
```

Comment: In your group by statement you have 3 columns and one of them is c.id. Which table is c ? Also you  have more than 3 columns in your select statements that are not part of aggregate function and this is not ok. What I want to say is that this is not true: "The following query works correctly..." so please share the one that works. Thanks!

Comment: You could perhaps do it "recursively": `(links LEFT JOIN sales GROUP BY link_id) LEFT JOIN clicks_source1 GROUP BY link_id` where at every "step", you `LEFT JOIN` a table, `SELECT` your `COUNT()` for that table, and use the entire result as basis for the next step

Answer (score 0):

you can just add inner joins with `links` to all the subqueries

```
select count(1) as ct, s.link_id, date(s.clicked) dt, 'sales' as col 
from sales s
join links l1 on l1.id = s.link_id
where s.clicked >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and s.clicked <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
group by date(s.clicked), s.link_id

union all etc.
```

Then you'll only get the rows with a match and the query should run faster